# Render collection of nested JSON Data

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a template file that takes in data from a JSON and displays it as a list

JSON -

```
    "items":[
      {
        "name":"a",
      },
      {
        "name":"b",
      },
      {
        "name":"c",
      }
    ]
```

JS File

```
var items= this.props.data.items.map(function(items){
        return <li key={items.name}><span className={items.name}></span><em>{items.name}</em></li>
})

//where it later gets rendered like so:

<div className="four columns main-col">
  <div className="bars">
     <ul className="items">
       {items}
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I want to modify the data, so that its more categorized, and will have nested objects

Example:

```
    "categorizedItems":[
      {
        "type":"a",
        "items":[
           {
             "name":"apple"
           },
           {
             "name":"banana"
           }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type":"b",
        "items":[
           {
             "name":"car"
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

So i thought, since it is a nested JSON object, I will need to map twice, so i tried the following:

```
var categories= this.props.data.categorizedItems.map(function(category){
      var items= category.items.map(function(item){
         return <li key={items.name}><span className={items.name}></span><em>{items.name}</em></li>
      })
      return <ul key={category.type}>{items}</ul>
})

//and i render it the same way

<div className="four columns main-col">
  <div className="categories">
       {categories}
  </div>
</div>
```

However this gives me errors saying "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
I dont understand how what I am doing (the nested mapping) is different from the original code (single mapping).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the errors in your code
Try this

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    type: "a",
    items: [
      {
        name: "apple"
      },
      {
        name: "banana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "b",
    items: [
      {
        name: "car"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const categories = data.map((category) => {
  const items = category.items.map(function (item) {
    return (
      <li key={item.name}>
        <span className={item.name}></span>
        <em>{item.name}</em>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return <ul key={category.type}>{items}</ul>;
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="four columns main-col">
      <div className="categories">{categories}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-noether-80ye9?file=/src/App.js:0-714

the problem in existing code.
Instead of

```
var categories= this.props.data.categorizedItems.map(function(category){
      var items= category.items.map(function(item){
         return <li key={items.name}><span className={items.name}></span><em>{items.name}</em></li>
      })
      return <ul key={category.type}>{items}</ul>
})
```

Try

```
var categories= this.props.data.categorizedItems.map(function(category){
      var items= category.items.map(function(item){
         return <li key={item.name}><span className={item.name}></span><em>{item.name}</em></li>
      })
      return <ul key={category.type}>{items}</ul>
})
```

Comment: There is no difference between the solution you are trying to show and my old code.
Solution provided also does not work, and there is a lack of explanation why yours supposedly works but mine does not.

Comment: did you check sandbox link?

Comment: comes to difference, `return <li key={items.name}><span className={items.name}></span><em>{items.name}</em></li>`
it should be `item.name`, not `items.name`

Comment: Yes ok your solution works for this example that was watered down joke piece of code to simulate a simplified version of my actual problem, so your solution is correct, just does not solve my problem. Because the ACTUAL problem lies in the latter half of my explanation not just the code snippet

Comment: it would be helpful if you could reproduce the issue on the sandbox. so other people get to know your issue.